# Can't read Avro files from AWS S3 path using PySpark locally

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am running pyspark version 2.3.2 locally and I can't seem to read from an S3 path on AWS.

The error I get is:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.load.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:709)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:390)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In earlier version of PySpark (2.2.0) I was able to use the following jars:
`hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar` and `aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar`
which I passed as arguments to PySpark on the command line. These do not seem to work with the latest version of PySpark (2.3.2)

I found this documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/cloud-integration.html

which suggested I should use the `hadoop-cloud_2.11` artifact. I tried passing to pyspark as follows:

`pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:hadoop-cloud_2.11:2.3.2`

But PySpark fails to find the specified package and I get this error:

```
module not found: org.apache.spark#hadoop-cloud_2.11;2.3.2
```

I'm not sure how to continue. I could try the hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk jars, but I'm not sure which versions are compatible with PySpark 2.3.2.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you check which version of hadoop jars are present in jars folder of spark installation ? if its hadoop 2.7.3 jar ,the above aws java sdk jar should work ? Are you passing s3 or s3a in pyspark while reading the file ?

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yes I was using s3, which I hadn't realised was deprecated. When I use s3a I don't get this exception. The jars in the spark installation are also 2.7.3.

Comment: Don't use "s3"; its been deleted except from the AWS EMR libraries, where it refers to something else entirely. w.r.t that spark-hadoop-cloud module; it's not currently published in the ASF releases, though it comes in from other people's